# Как прописать пути, что б в docker_compose что б работал редирект nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, redirect

Я хочу сделать обычный редирект из nginx и поместить это в доккер.
Как это можно сделать и как подключить nginx.conf?
Он имеет такой вид

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass: http://loadbalancer;
    };
}
```

docker_compose имеет такую секцию, но я не разберусь с путями.

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

В самом проекте есть папка nginx, где есть nginx.config, но это всё либо не запускается, либо пишет `nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1`

Как запустить, что б nginx проксировал либо на приложения во внутренней сети доккер либо в наружной, как сейчас - при обращении на 80 порт, что б передавались данные с 4000 порта, на котором веб сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с того, что у вас некорректный `nginx.conf`.

Nginx ругается на `upstream`? Значит, вы используете конфиг напрямую, а не через `sites-enabled`: конфиги из этой папки грузятся в контекст `http`. Соответственно, вам нужно обернуть ваш конфиг в `http { .. }`

Когда вы это сделаете, то Nginx вас последовательно обругает за то, что нет `;` после `server 127.0.0.1:4000`, за то, что есть `:` после `proxy_pass` и за то, что есть `;` в строке `};` закрывающей блок `location`. После того, как вы всё исправите, ваш фал будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
events {}

http {
    upstream loadbalancer {
        server 127.0.0.1:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }
    }
}
```

Про подключение к докеру я ничего не понял. Вы хотите, чтобы `nginx` работал в докере? Ок, без проблем.

Во-первых, вам нужно отпамить порты. Как минимум добавить в docker-compose директиву `ports: "80:80"`, чтобы внутренний порт 80 докера стал связан с портом 80 хоста.

Во-вторых, если вы перемапливаете `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` на свой файл, то вам не требуется перемапливать `/etc/nginx/conf.d` так как вы в своём конфиге этим каталогом не пользуетесь.

Теперь про приложение.

На какой машине находится порт `4000`? У вас в конфиге написано `127.0.0.1`. В рамках той конфигурации, которую вы показали, этот адрес находится внутри контейнера. Но там явно ничего нет на порту 4000.

Следовательно, это хост.  Тогда не требуется прокидывать порты, а достаточно добавить в сервис nginx инструкцию `network_mode: "host"`. Но это нелогично. Раз вы засунули nginx внутрь контейнера, то и вебсервис логично тоже запаковать в контейнер. НАпример, добавить в docker-compose.yaml сервис `web-app`, тогда ваше приложение будет доступно из контейнера `nginx` как `web-app:4000`